# Loop break from listener

Tags: python, linux

I am looking for a simple python process that starts to run in the background that with a loop counts up the minutes. I want to send a signal (from outside the script) to the process to break the loop. There may be a number of these scripts opening and running simultaneously.

```
while True:
    timer=timer+1
    time.sleep(60)
    # listener that receives a signal from outside the program
    # to stop the loop return timer and then end the program
    if (timeup==True):
        break
```

Comment: You want Python, you say, but your title and tags both refer to PHP. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I would prefer php but after doing some basic research, it would seem that it would be easier done in python or c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#module-signal)

```
import signal, time, os

abort = False
def stop(sig, stack):
        global abort
        print('Got signal!')
        abort = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, stop)

print('My pid: %s' % os.getpid())

while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Hello')

        if (abort):
                break
```

Which will output something like:

```
[~]% python test.py
My pid: 24341
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

You can then use `kill(1)` to send the signal:

```
[~]% kill -USR1 24341
```

As far as I can find, there's no obvious way to send the signal from Python, but you could use just start `kill` with the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module (bit ugly, but works).

You can use the same technique in PHP by the way. See [`pcntl_signal()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) (You will need the `pcntl` module installed).

Also see:

- [Introduction to UNIX Signals and System Calls](http://ph7spot.com/musings/introduction-to-unix-signals-and-system-calls)
- [All about Linux signals](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals)

Other methods of Inter process communication (IPC) you could use might be:

- File with status
- Shared memory
- FIFO
- Sending data over network (also works well when two programs are on the same machine)

I'm not going to provide examples for all of these, IMHO using a signal is the most obvious choice here.